# Customer Mobile API for Magento 2.3

Tags: rest-api, mobile, webapi

I am trying to create a mobile app for a Magento 2.3 CE site, So far I have found where the Swagger documentation is and have managed to log in as a customer using the integrate endpoint.

What I don't understand is how I get the products and categories using the customer token, they all seem to require a admin token

Comment: You don't need the customer token to get the products. Your should be using graphql API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorial as they have explained it very nicely

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-all-products-orders-categories-magento-2.html

**Follow the below settings to fix the API issue.**

**Login to Admin >> Stores >> Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> SERVICES >> Magento Web API >> Web API Security >> Allow Anonymous Guest Access: Yes**

**Please Note If this does not work for you then downgrading your php version will solve the issue**

Hope it helps!

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use this and got `"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",`

Comment: you might be using php 7.1??

Comment: My server is running on php 7.3

Comment: check updated ans

Comment: Would this let unauthorised requests view the data to? because if possible i would like it to still be locked down to logged in customers

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/anonymous-api-security.html#:~:text=To%20disable%20this%20feature%2C%20log,Allow%20Anonymous%20Guest%20Access%20menu.

Comment: you can try it though we cant say anything as i have not faced the issue like this but the ans is based from best of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to take admin token using the admin username and password.
Using that token, you can get product and category.

You can check this using either swagger or postman.

I hope it helps.
Thank you.

Comment: In my question I did say I knew how to get the data using an admin token but this is for an android app to let customers make orders with the site so I cant use admin token.